# Xskak and xetex: alternative font

Tags: fonts, xetex, chess, xskak

Good day. 
It's a second week I can't solve the problem. I have a font ChessSanPin, installed in my system (Ubuntu). Xetex uses it  well itself (using fontspec). 
For example:

[image: ChessSanPin with fontspec]

But if I try to use it with Xskak package, I've get a warning

> LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `LSB/ChessSanPin/m/n' undefined (Font) 
>   using`LSB/skaknew/m/n' instead on input line 19.
>
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXgxG.png) (./chess.aux)
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults
>   substituted.

and default font skaknew is used.

Document source:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xskak}

\begin{document}

\setboardfontfamily{ChessSanPin}

\newcommand\testboard{{%
\boardfont
\noindent
rmblkans\\
opopopop\\
0Z0Z0Z0Z\\
Z0Zqj0Z0\\
0Z0LKZ0Z\\
Z0Z0Z0Z0\\
POPOPOPO\\
SNAQJBMR\par}}
\testboard

\end{document}
```

And I can't understand, is there a problem of a font, of a document or some other.

Could you help me, please, to make it work?

Comment: If it is a type1 font it should be possible, but it involves some work. Is the font freely available somewhere?

Comment: It is a postcsript commercial font, so I can't upload it anywhere.

Comment: You can find in the chessfss documentation some explanations about the steps to use such a font.

Comment: I've found it, but it doesnt help. I hope, there is someone, who has an experience in using alternative fonts in xskak and xetex.

Comment: Well I do have experience. After all I wrote chessfss, and I created the enpassant package but to create the needed installation files one needs at least the name of the font and the .afm (for the encoding vector and the tfm-file) and if possible also the pfb for the tests.

Comment: I have both amf and pfb files. 
PFB is installed as a system font
`/usr/share/fonts/postscript/ChessSanPin.pfb: ChessSanPin:style=Regular` 
and it's available via fontspec. 
Could you tell me, please, what have I do to make this font available from xskak?

Comment: A complete installation instruction is in the chessfss documentation starting from 10.5.2 Installing the type1-fonts – the brute force methode.

Comment: As I understood it's related to LaTeX (year 2006), but I'm talking about XeTeX, which can understand system fonts. 
Is it possible to use it?

Comment: No. xetex is good at unicode fonts. But unicode doesn't support the full set of chess symbols. Also you have a normal postscript font, which means that the glyphs are in non-standard positions so you can't avoid the reencoding (unless you want to write your own chess package which hard codes the positions). It is perhaps possible to load the font as system font and use a teckit mapping as reencoding, but this wouldn't mean less work and imho the tfm-way is easier (and tested).

Comment: But xskak itself uses pfb-font (SkakNew-Diagram.pfb). My font is designed on its base.

Comment: xetex can use .pfb files, but you need quite a number of helper files. There exist a SkakNew-Diagram.tfm, quite a number of XXXskaknew.fd-files and a skaknew.map-file. If your font uses the same glyph names and positions as skaknew and has the same character set, you only need to create a tfm from the afm, and your own variants of all the helper files.

Comment: And all info about generation of these helpers is in your http://ctan.altspu.ru/macros/latex/contrib/chessfss/chessfss.pdf manual? But it's 10 years old, is it actual at the moment, especially for XeTeX?

Comment: you can use skaknew in xetex with this method, so why shouldn't it work for your font? Beside this: go and check my reputation and then decide if you want to trust me or not.

Comment: I havo no doubt to trust you or not ;)
But it seems to me rather difficult to plug-in new font into xskak doc. 
I've concidered, that my font needs to have an LSB shape, is it right? As far, as it have no LSB shape, there is an error "Font shape LSB/ChessSanPin/m/n' undefined", isn't it?

Comment: And again a "but". You still hope that I'm wrong and that someone comes around the corner with an one-line solution.

Comment: No, you're wrong. Now I'm trying to understand is it possible to make my font work, whatever it has no LSB shape, or I have to ask font developers to add this shape.

Comment: You can't add an "LSB shape" to your font. What is the file name of your font? Has it all the glyphs that are also present in skaknew-diagramm? Are the glyphs at the same positions?

Comment: Yes, font has the same glyphs at same positions: http://s018.radikal.ru/i512/1610/ae/34fe208d2596.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Put the afm and the pfb of your font in some empty test folder. Open a command line there and run

```
  afm2tfm ChessSanPin
```

this should create a tfm. (You could also create the tfm with fontforge).

Then create a test document in the same folder with the tfm with this content:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{lsbchesssanpin.fd}
\ProvidesFile{lsbchesssanpin.fd}
        [2016/10/20 v1.0 Chess font definitions]

\DeclareFontFamily{LSB}{chesssanpin}{}
 \DeclareFontShape{LSB}{chesssanpin}{m}{n}{<-> ChessSanPin}{}
\end{filecontents}

\pdfmapline{=ChessSanPin ChessSanPin <ChessSanPin.pfb}
\setboardfontfamily{chesssanpin}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard

\end{document}
```

Compile it with *pdflatex* (not xelatex). If it works come back and I will tell you how to create the correct map entry for xelatex.

If you are on linux be carefull with the uppercase/lowercase in the file names.

Comment: Yes, it works!
http://s008.radikal.ru/i303/1610/be/20243de3441b.png

Comment: Which texsystem are you using? miktex or texlive?

Comment: Texlive on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Change the pdfmapfile line to `\pdfmapline{chesssanpin default ChessSanPin}`. Does this work for you with xelatex?

Comment: PDF generated well

Comment: As I understood, now I have to generate .map file?

Comment: You should do `ChessSanPin ChessSanPin <ChessSanPin.pfb` in a `chesssanpin.map`, store the map-file in your local texmf and then enable the map with updmap-sys. Then it should work without the `\pdfmapline` command.

Comment: Now document 

`\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xskak}

\setboardfontfamily{chesssanpin}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\testboard{{%
\boardfont
\noindent
rmblkans\\
opopopop\\
0Z0Z0Z0Z\\
Z0Zqj0Z0\\
0Z0LKZ0Z\\
Z0Z0Z0Z0\\
POPOPOPO\\
SNAQJBMR\par}}
\testboard

\end{document}`

Comment: All these files (fd, map, etc.) have to be located in some specific folders in /usr/share/texfm?
It doesn't work without these files in current folder.

Comment: I've put it in:
    *.map -> /usr/share/texfm/fonts/map/dvips/public/chess/
    *.tfm -> /usr/share/texfm/fonts/tfm/public/chess/
    *.pfb -> /usr/share/texfm/fonts//type1/public/chess/
    *.fd -> /usr/share/texfm/tex/latex/chess/
and run updmap-sys

Comment: Error is the same, but now it uses my own fd-file: http://s019.radikal.ru/i610/1610/7c/42a9eace29ff.png

Comment: Sorry, there's no any error.